# tippingtable2gui - Formatting Troubles C#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with the formatting. However, I cannot seem to get it to look proper.

I was told to initialize the tipRate before the entering the nested while loop or to use just a for loop. but still I am having trouble with the formatting.

[What it should look like](http://i1006.photobucket.com/albums/af188/Jesse_Jackel/Correct_zpsooq6xq7c.jpg)

[What mine looks like](http://i1006.photobucket.com/albums/af188/Jesse_Jackel/Wrong_zpsbjqksxdv.jpg)

Here is my code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // Constants
        const double TIPSTEP = 0.05;
        const double DINNERSTEP = 10.00;    

        // Variables
        double maxRate = Convert.ToDouble (maxTip.Text);
        double lowRate = Convert.ToDouble (minTip.Text);
        double minDinner = Convert.ToDouble (minPrice.Text);
        double maxDinner = Convert.ToDouble (maxPrice.Text);
        double dinnerPrice = Convert.ToDouble (minPrice.Text);
        double tipRate;
        double tip;

        tipRate = lowRate;

        label1.Text = "";
        label6.Text = "";
        label7.Text = "";
        label9.Text = "Price";

        for (tipRate = lowRate; tipRate <= maxRate; tipRate += TIPSTEP)
            label1.Text = label1.Text + String.Format("{0, 8}", tipRate.ToString("F")) + "\t";
            label1.Text = label1.Text + String.Format("{0, 8}", tipRate.ToString("C")) + "\t";

        label8.Text="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";

        while (dinnerPrice <= maxDinner)
            {
                label6.Text = label6.Text + String.Format("{0, 8}" + "\n", dinnerPrice.ToString("C")) + "\t";
                while (tipRate <= maxRate)
                    {
                        tip = dinnerPrice * tipRate;
                        label7.Text = label7.Text + String.Format("{0, 8}", tip.ToString("F")) + "\t";
                        tipRate += 0.05;
                    } 
                dinnerPrice += DINNERSTEP;
                tipRate = lowRate;
            }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should write this out in pseudocode, then convert the pseudocode to actual code.  You want to loop through all the possible prices and for each of those prices loop through all the possible tip percentages.  Where you "initialize" your variables is important.

```
initialize dinnerprice, maxDinner and maxTip

while dinnerprice <= maxDinner
begin
    set the tiprate to minimum  (This needs to be done at the start of every dinnerprice)

    while tiprate <= maxtiprate
    begin
        calculate tip
        print the tip in the appropriate place
        increment the tiprate
    end

    increment the dinnerprice
end
```

Comment: Alright, would that fix the format of how the output would look like? This did help but i really just need to figure out how to get the output aligned properly